# ¿Cómo crear una App independiente pero como motor use Google Chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, aplicación-web, google-chrome

Hace unos días navegando por Internet me encontré con este Link: https://cybmeta.com/ el punto es que en Google Chrome, vi que en la parte derecha de la URL me aparecía un Icono de "descarga" al darle click me creo un acceso directo a la pagina que tenia abierta.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se que se puede hacer algo parecido si le doy click a los tres puntitos, luego en "Más herramientas" y por ultimo en "Crear acceso directo..." pero, ¿cómo se hace para que funcione como en esta pagina? (link arriba).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

También al darle click derecho en la aplicación para escritorios de GitHub, me aparece una parte de "abrir consola" (o algo así) y es la misma consola de Chrome. (creo que vi lo mismo en Atom). ¿estas aplicaciones usan Chrome o estan basadas en Chromium? ¿qué tecnología usan?

-¡Gracias por tomar el tiempo de leer! ;)

Comment: Parece tratarse de una PWA(*Progressive Web App*), parten de usar un *webview* para *lanzarse en una instancia del navegador*, te recomiendo este [enlace para conocer mas](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/codelabs/your-first-pwapp?hl=es), ahora tu pregunta pudiera terminar cerrada, pues tecnologías para lograrlo hay muchas pasando por el lenguaje en su estado puro (JS) y/o usando algún framework como Angular

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## PWA

> en Google Chrome, vi que en la parte derecha de la URL me aparecía un Icono de "descarga" al darle click me creo un acceso directo a la pagina que tenia abierta.
>   ...  ¿cómo se hace para que funcione como en esta pagina?

Lo que estás viendo en esa página es una [PWA](https://developers.google.com/web/progressive-web-apps/).

**Qué son las PWA?**

Las PWA o Progressive Web Applications son aplicaciones web (en buenas cuentas un sitio web) que ofrecen al usuario la experiencia de una aplicación nativa:

- Preserva gran parte de su funcionalidad (o toda) incluso offline
- Los recursos estáticos se cargan instantáneamente
- Se puede quitar el marco y barra de direcciones del browser para disponer de toda la pantalla
- Se accede desde un ícono en el escritorio
- Preserva el estado entre ejecuciones
- Establecen (pero se puede revocar) afinidad de links, de manera que cuando pinches links a ese sitio se abran en la PWA
- Mediante tecnologías como web-push notifications y el acceso a recursos locales como ubicación y cámara, proveen un nivel de interacción que trasciende al sitio web propiamente tal

Todo lo anterior utilizando el browser y evitando así instalar un seudobrowser propio que es peso muerto.

---

**Qué ventajas tienen**

Si bien tienen limitaciones con respecto a aplicaciones nativas instaladas via Play Store (por ejemplo el uso de bluetooth, por nombrar uno), tienen algunas ventajas:

- Abordan la resitencia en aumento que la gente siente a la hora de instalar *otra aplicación más*
- Utilizan la GUI del browser, luego no necesitas almacenar, en el teléfono, más que los datos en caché.
- Tienen un ámbito de permisos mucho más limitado que las apps nativas, muchas de las cuales no hacen nada no puedas hacer en el browser pero al instalarse en el teléfono *pueden* tener acceso a tus contactos, llamadas y archivos (la gente suele aceptar los permisos sin mirarlos siquiera)
- Es trivial convertir un sitio web en una PWA, vs la curva de aprendizaje necesaria para desarrollar apps nativas o generarlas con React Native o Nativescript (u otros generadores/frameworks)
- No hace falta pasar por un proceso de revisión y postulación via Play Store, justamente porque el ámbito de permisos limitado acota los posibles vectores de ataque de apps maliciosas (acota, no elimina)

Puedes probar PWAs que ha sustituido exitosamente a sus versiones nativas por ejemplo en [Twitter Mobile](https://mobile.twitter.com/), o Instagram (pero sólo lo ofrece con user agents móviles)

---

**Qué browsers las soportan?**

El diálogo de "agregar al escritorio" a.k.a. **beforeinstallprompt** tiene soporte de navegadores móviles -**en Android**- como Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Samsung Browser (gran browser, lo recomiendo)

Además, si bien partieron como una solución enfocada a la experiencia móvil, en Chrome 70 se lanzó para Windows 10 el soporte para **instalar PWAs en escritorio**. Esto fue paulatinamente incorporado en otros sistemas operativos hasta alcanzar cobertura completa en Chrome 73. De la misma manera, en Windows 10 [Microsoft Edge](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/progressive-web-apps#current-availability) las soporta y hasta [lista PWA en el Microsoft Store](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/progressive-web-apps/microsoft-store).

---

**Cómo se hace una PWA?**

Cuando se cumplen ciertos requisitos, un sitio web ofrece el diálogo para ser instalado (o bien aparece la opción en la barra de direcciones, como viste en escritorio). Esos requisitos son:

**1.-** incluir un [manifiesto](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/) (manifest.json) en el HTML:

```
<link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">
```

En el cual deben existir al menos las entradas:

- name o short_name (basta con una, se puede poner ambas)
- icons (al menos los íconos de 192px y 512px. Se puede añadir más)
- start_url (e.g. /index.html)
- display (debe ser `fullscreen`, `standalone`, o `minimal-ui`)

**2.-** Debe ser ofrecida via **https**

Específicamente en Chrome, también está el requisito de

**3.-** registrar un ServiceWorker que maneje el evento Fetch.

Esto es lo que permite cachear el sitio mediante reglas explícitas (en vez de headers de expiración) y ofrecer instantaneidad y funcionalidad offline en visitas posteriores.

[Puedes seguir este tutorial para hacer tu primera PWA](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/codelabs/your-first-pwapp?hl=es)

---

**Y qué desventajas tienen?**

Lamentablemente, en iOS Safari no existe el diálogo de "agregar al escritorio" (pero se puede hacer igual, si abres el menú)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tampoco hay soporte para notificaciones push, más que nada porque Apple maneja todo con Apple Push Notification Service (APNS) y en cambio el estándar webpush implica permitir que otro proveedor (Firebase, Onesignal o el mismo dueño del sitio web que instales) las maneje.

Hay otros problemas (algunos manejables, todos frustrantes) en PWAs en iOS en general. Esperemos que en el mediano plazo mejoren ese enfoque, por el bien de todos.

**¿No sirve usar Chrome en iOS?** No. Los third party browsers de iOS no son, como en Android, apps independientes, sino cáscaras que delegan en Safari con los mismos impedimentos.

---

**Webviews**

Dado que el caché via Service Workers, y el look & feel en pantalla completa funcionan transversalmente en Android e iOS , una posible salida a las limitaciones de PWA en este último es **combinar aplicaciones nativas con PWA**.

En este enfoque la app nativa es una cáscara que contiene un webview (lo cual es, como quien dice, un iframe). Con esto la cáscara puede encargarse de las notificaciones via APNS y delegar todo o casi todo lo demás a la PWA que se está mostrando en el webview.

No es la panacea. Los webviews en iOS tienen comportamientos distintos a Safari en cuanto a uso de memoria, acceso a la cámara via WebRTC, y más.

---

## Electron

> ...al darle click derecho en la aplicación para escritorios de
>   GitHub, me aparece una parte de "abrir consola" (o algo así) y es la
>   misma consola de Chrome. (creo que vi lo mismo en Atom). ¿estas
>   aplicaciones usan Chrome o estan basadas en Chromium? ¿qué tecnología
>   usan?

Eso que ves es [Electron JS](https://electronjs.org/), un framework que permite hacer apps de escritorio combinando Chromium (como GUI) y NodeJS. Así como Atom hay muchas apps de escritorio que lo utilizan: [Slack, Postman, Discord, Visual Studio Code y muchas otras](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2019/02/best-electron-apps).

A diferencia de una PWA, Electron se instala nativamente en escritorio, por lo cual la aplicación tiene acceso a multithreading, el sistema de archivos y otros aspectos de bajo nivel que una PWA nunca tendrá.

Comment: ¡wow!... Muchísimas, muchísimas gracias. Sin duda ha sido la respuesta mas completa que he recibido en cualquier lado de Internet. ¡Mil y un gracias!

Comment: He pasado el último año leyendo todo lo que se publica al respecto. El tema me fascina y, como en todo, siempre queda al menos un 51% que aprender